# WorkFlow with SharePoint Designer 2010 - how to set value from current list item

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, tasks

How to set value from current list item to a field in a custom task? 
Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a task that gets created by your workflow inside "Start Custom Task Process" (or any of the task process actions) then:

1. From the workflow editor, click the Task Process link
2. Under Customization, click **Change the behavior of a single task**
3. In Step(Before a Task is Assigned), add action: **Set Task Field**
4. field: Select the field you want to set
5. value: click the function button and choose CurrentItem and the field you want to get

Comment: Is it possible from "Collect data from a User" Task action?

Comment: I can collect data When a Task Completes, cool. Thanks for reply.